# Context.Items vs local variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httprequest

I store my User class in the Context.Items property of HttpRequest for use throughout the page.

I need to reference this several times, maybe 10's of times if I'm using a repeater.

Is retrieving from context.items expensive? For example should I be fetching it and storing as a local variable, or is accessing it many times directly ok?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a local variable, use a local variable. Not only does it reduce overhead, it also makes your code shorter and easier to read and maintain (no "magic strings").

[Context.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) is designed for situations where you *cannot* use a local variable:

> Gets a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share data between an IHttpModule interface and an IHttpHandler interface during an HTTP request.

Thus, you would use Context.Items to transfer information between two objects that handle *the same request* but which don't have access to the same `Page` object. Concrete examples would be:

- Passing data between two pages with `Server.Transfer`.
- Passing data between `Application_BeginRequest` and the page.
- Passing data between a custom `IHttpModule` (for example, a custom authentication handler) and the page.

Comment: thats how I use it. It's created via global.asax and then reused in master page and page